# Why did python poetry download different packages compared to the project's repository?

Tags: python, jupyter, pypi, pyzmq, python-poetry

I installed jupyter using poetry. Typing the command 'jupyter' returns a list options I have available, so the installation was a success, but when I run the command 'jupyter notebook' an error appears saying some modules cannot be found.

On further investigation I discovered some package files on my machine are missing when compared to the project's github repository. Is poetry not working properly, or is the repository which poetry is downloading the files from (pypi?) not up-to-date?

[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ortbf.png)

[Screenshot of the files on my system. Highlighted are the files which are different from the repository's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yHC4.png)

[Screenshot of the files on the project's github repository. Highlighted files for comparison with above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBRbx.png)

Comment: Please _don't_ post screenshots of error messages. Post them as `formatted text`.

Comment: The last release version on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq/#history) on `2021-09-16`. That commit on [Github](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/commit/70d11b6b0e46720a908404c8d954b10e0b4e59e0#diff-bbb7ea586d690958786ec6ea63b478c278dd0bd8407452d8f7b48d8dac463444) happened on `2021-11-23`. A GitHub `main` branch is almost never what you install for ANY software following a release cycle.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.